My graph curves look stepped even though I have removed the stepped modifier, is there something I did wrong?

Hello, I am currently having this issue on the screenshot, the graphs look to have stepped interpolation even though I have removed the stepped interpolation modifier. I have no idea what might be the cause of this. Please help.

Hard to see what's going on there with all the keyfames and handles... have you set the keyframe interpolation mode to something like Constant instead of Bézier or Linear?

As Gordon says, maybe you need to switch from Constant to Bezier, what does it give if you press T?

Yes I made sure that the interpolation wasn't in constant, it is all in Bezier, that stepped interpolation only comes in whenever I add a modifier like the cycle one, but when I remove the modifier it goes with it. Let me add on some more pictures with a closer screenshot to show this.

If the keyframes' values are really close or even nearly identical, the curve might show steps between keyframes even though the Interpolation isn't stepped. The normalize display can exacerbate this phenomenon.

So are 6 frames before the next pose, does that count as being close to each other? sincerely asking, it is not a quip or anything like that.

What is weird is that it only occurs whenever I add modifiers, without any the interpolation is fine and is in Bezier.
